# Error message while inserting image into excel

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to display an image into an excel sheet using poi. Here's the source code :

```
//...reading inputStream
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
//Debugging shows that pictureIdx value is 0
int pictureIdx = workbook.addPicture(bytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();       
CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
anchor.setCol1(1); 
anchor.setRow1(1); 
Picture pict = drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIdx);
//...Saving workbook
```

When I open the generated excel file, no image is displayed and I am getting instead this error message :
    `Repaired records: Drawing from /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml-Part (Drawingsform)`

Any help will be more appreciated. Many Thanks.

p.s: I am using Java 8 and MS Excel 2013

Comment: I figured it out. The problem is related to the anchor object. Most of the snippet-code examples don't provide the right solution. Actually we should define Col2 and Row2 anchor's attributes as well. Which solves the problem.

Comment: An one cell anchor is also possible. But then the `Picture` needs to be [resized](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Picture.html#resize()) because a one cell anchor cannot determine the picture's size.